# Where to put a firestore listener in a React-redux app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

Should I put firestore listener in a useEffect hook inside the component like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("courses")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => dispatch(setCourses(extractDocs(snapshot))));

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

or in a redux middleware and return the unsubscribe method like so:

```
export const subscribeToCourses = () => (dispatch) => {
  return firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("courses")
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      dispatch(setCourses(extractDocs(snapshot)));
    });
};
```

What's the right way and way?

Comment: Redux middleware function provides a medium to interact with dispatched action before they reach the reducer, I see no point in handling the subscription there. I think that setting a listener to the database with useEffect + onSnapshot is much more appropiate (the 1st option). I would even set the state of my componenet inside the useEffect function upon database changes directly instead of with redux :)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay That makes sense! But I need the courses list in Redux because when a specific course is clicked I want to show some info about it in the new page, so I retrieve it from Redux instead of sending another request. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I think that should be fine, you can store your info in the redux store that is kind of a global state, or in some of your components state of your component hierarchy. I would not think much about that as it can be also a matter of taste or the approach you might be more familiar with. First I would make my app work, and then maybe care about the best way to do things. I find [this](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=context+vs+redux) video very useful to understand both approaches and find the one that suits you best :)